# Are all elements draggable in HTML5, I want <Audio> to be draggable, is that possible?

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I am trying to implement drag and drop of certain elements in my website. But I failed in implementing the drag and drop events with audio tag element.

- Are all HTML(5) elements "draggable" ?
- If not what are not? or 
  at least tell me  supports draggable? if so how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

html5 supports to use draggable on elements.

```
<audio draggable="true"></audio>
```

See compatibility for [draggable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/draggable#Browser_compatibility).